# click on body except some other tag not working

Tags: jquery, except, document-body

does anyone know if css position:relative; can mess up the function

```
    $('body').not($('.theDIV')).click(function(){
    alert('');

    });
```

or the problem is somewhere else?

what is happening is i have a  that appears on click of a button and i want it to hide() when i click anywhere on the body, except the div itself. 
 HTML

```
<ul class='messages'> //these are made dynamically. should i use each() to go through all the elements?
<li>
    <div class='theDIV'></div>
    <input type='button'>
</li>
<li>
    <div class='theDIV'></div>
    <input type='button'>
</li>
<li>
    <div class='theDIV'></div>
    <input type='button'>
</li>
</ul>
```

sorry if i wasnt clear the first time

Comment: why are you doing this in an each?

Comment: what's your html code? even if you have 2 $('.messages li ') they mess each other .not(). What exactly you're trying to make?

Comment: code makes no sense, body can never be a descendent of any LI, so `not` is worthless, and you are adding new click handler to body for every one of the elements

Comment: i changed the code, now i hope its easier to understand

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6610022/jquery-close-div-by-clicking-anywhere-apart-from-the-div-itself

Answer (score 6):

You could do

```
$('body').click(function(e){
   if(! $(e.target).hasClass('theDIV')){
     alert('clicked on something that has not the class theDIV');
   }

});
```