# Click HTML except one element, without using jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, dom, onclick

I show us the code:

```
(function (){
  var element = document.getElementById('bar'), hideElement = document.getElementById('foo'),
  var html = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0];
  tool.onclick = function() {
    hideElement.style.display = 'block';
    html.onclick = function() {
      hideElement.style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
})();
```

This piece of code work's fine, but, after clicking html, I can not reopen the hidden element.

I want to click the html element and give display:none to hideElement, then to click the element id="bar", give to the hidden element display:block, but instead of click the element foo, click the html element. What I can do?

Oh, i need help WITHOUT JQUERY, thanks :)

EDIT: something like that : [click on body except some other tag not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9711134/click-on-body-except-some-other-tag-not-working) , but without JQuery,

Comment: Is it a typo? `hideElement.display` instead of `hideElement.style.display`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure it's going to answer your question, but here it is: how to handle an event on the body except one element:

```
document.documentElement.onclick = function(e) {
    var evt = e || window.event, // IE...
        target = evt.target || evt.srcElement // IE again...
    // There, "target" is the element clicked. See where I'm going?
    if (target.id !== "foo") {
        // Do w/e you want if the page was clicked, except for "foo"
    }
}
```

This is the concept of "event bubbling". You can listen to one element and all its children at once, and get the target as specified in the code up there.

Comment: Glad it suits you. Be careful about cross-browser compatibility though. In a perfect world, `var target = e.target` would be enough. But IE doesn't like `e` passed as an argument (so we use `window.event`), and old versions of FF didn't like `evt.target` (so we use `evt.srcElement`).

Comment: `e.srcElement` should be `evt.srcElement`, and `.srcElement` is an IE property, not FF. Pretty sure FF has always had `.target`.

Comment: Oops, typo. My bad about `srcElement`! You're right indeed :)

Comment: I'd recommend adding an if block for the existence of `evt`. I was bitten by this today in Opera.

Comment: Could you edit my answer to add it? I don't see where to add this.

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't appear to be defining `tool` anywhere that I can see.

Second, you forgot `.style` in `hideElement.display` (should be `hideElement.style.display`).

Third, `document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0]` is redundant. Just use `document.documentElement` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
html.onclick = function() {
  hideElement.display = 'none';
}
```

to

```
html.onclick = function() {
  hideElement.style.display = 'none';
}
```

Comment: Its only a mistake, but this is not what I need

Comment: That mistake is enough to break it. There is no such thing as 'only a mistake' in programming.